# VueJS and Datatable

Tags: vue.js, datatable

I am using datatable and vuejs together. Datatable is inside the vuejs componentn and successfuly initialized by vuejs component.
But I have some question about how to use vuejs methods clicking a checkbox element that inside datatable row.

```
            {
                "title": "Listeleme", "data": "a",
                "render": function (data, type, row) {
                    if (data === true) {
                        return '<input type="checkbox" id="A' + row.id +  '" onclick="checkboxChange(this)" data-role="checkbox" data-type="a" checked>';
                    } else {
                        return '<input type="checkbox" id="A' + row.id + '" onclick="checkboxChange(this)" data-role="checkbox" data-type="a">';
                    }
                }
            },
```

I need to change **onclick="checkboxChange(this)"** as **v-on:click="checkboxChange"** to access vuejs component method

Note : If I write directly vuejs methods name as above , can not access the methods. It is just doing nothing

thank you.

Answer (score 0):

found a solution.

added Vue application instance to window

```
window.application= new Vue({
});
```

and created component

```
const someComponent= Vue.component('some-component',{
methods:{
  vueJSFunction:function(){
    }
}});
```

from outside the component I can access the VueJS component methods

```
function someFunction(obj) {
    window.Application.$children[0].vueJSFunction();
}
```